# Opening several IPython consoles in Spyder

Tags: ipython, spyder

I am using Spyder and I would like to open several IPython consoles but I don't want to switch among them to see the results like you see in the figure, I want them to be displayed independently, so I can compare results from several simulations. Is that possible?

[image]